# Rails preload query via joined table filter

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, eager-loading

I am querying a bunch of letters that were written by and received by people.  I am associating the letters table to the people table by way of a join table that determines whether that person is a creator or recipient for the letter in question using a persontype identifier (0 = creator, 1 = recipient).

My problem:  I am displaying 50 letters at a time in a view for the user with information like the date, creator, recipient, and museum collection that the letter can be found in.  The page loads very slowly because, though I have figured out how to "include" collections so that a query is not run on each letter being displayed, I have not been able to do this for creators and recipients.  If I simply displayed "people" I could also do an includes, but since I am filtering the people by their role, rails is running several queries for each letter in the view and this takes around 6000 ms.  Without creators and recipients the view loads in about 250 ms.

Here are the basics of my models:

```
class ArchiveObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :archive_object_people
    has_many :people, :through => :archive_object_people

class ArchiveObjectPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :archive_object
    belongs_to :person

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :archive_object_people
    has_many :archive_objects, :through => :archive_object_people
```

I have also created some scopes and methods in the models to help me.
In archive_object.rb

```
# These can be used to distinguish recipients from creators of letters
# Use case:  ArchiveObject.first.creators
def recipients
  people.where("archive_object_people.persontype = '1'")
end
def creators
  people.where("archive_object_people.persontype = '0'")
end

scope :recipients, lambda {
  joins(:people).where("archive_object_people.persontype = '1'")
}
scope :creators, lambda {
  joins(:people).where("archive_object_people.persontype = '0'")
}
```

I want to preload the creators and recipients the same way that I am including, say, the location of the letters so that I can iterate through each letter and display letter.title, letter.creators, letter.collection, etc without running dozens of queries.  For example: ArchiveObject.includes(:collections, :creators)

Things I have attempted so far.  All of these will run another query when getting recipients / creators although they may not run another query when just looking at generic "people":

```
ArchiveObject.joins(:people).where("archive_object_people.persontype = '1'").preload(:people)

ArchiveObject.includes(:people, :archive_object_people).first.recipients

ArchiveObject.includes(:recipients)  => raises an exception
```

I also started reading about redefining the has_many and using a condition to only pull creators or recipients, but I would actually need two associations, in that case:  a has_many creators and a has_many recipients.  I do not know how to set that up but if anybody has any ideas, that would be rad.

Thanks for any help or advice you can give me!  I would love to figure this out so that I have a super speedy and efficient site.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  It took me a few hours but I figured it out!

I removed all of my custom utility methods and rewrote some has_many type of things.

```
class ArchiveObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :archive_object_people
  has_many :people, :through => :archive_object_people

  has_many :creators, -> { where "archive_object_people.persontype = '0'" },
           :through => :archive_object_people
           :source => :person
  has_many :recipients, -> { where "archive_object_people.persontype = '1'" },
           :through => :archive_object_people,
           :source => :person
```

With the following in the model, you can do stuff like this:

```
test = ArchiveObject.includes(:people, :creators, :recipients)
test.first.people  # => list of all people on first object
test.first.creators # => list of all people who are creators on first object
test.first.recipients # => all people who are recipients
```

I was able to get that information before with my custom methods but NOW with the includes you can preload them so that it runs a massive query upfront and then doesn't need to rerun it again when pulling information for each letter.

I hope this helps somebody else out there.  Note that the :source in the has_many descriptions is to :person, not :people, which caused me some temporary anguish.